# How to present a UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I get an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The `didTapUserScreenButton()` works fine though, the `didTapChatControllerButton()` gives the error. I'm thinking it might get the error because the `didTapChatControllerButton()` goes to a `UiCollectionViewController?` and the other works fine as it's going to a `UITableViewController?`.

```
func didTapChatControllerButton() {
    let chat_log_controller = ChatLogController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chat_log_controller!)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func didTapUserScreenButton() {
    let user_screen_vc = usersScreenVC()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: user_screen_vc)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Use camelCase instead of snake_case in Swift variable names.

Comment: `let chat_log_controller = ChatLogController` What' is it supposed to do exactly? Missing the init => `ChatLogController()`? Or just an error of copy/paste, and you want to init it from a xib or a storyboard?, in which case all the IBOulet are already connected and explain your error?

Comment: If it is a UICollectionViewController, you should supply it with a layout

Answer (score 0):

You missed the (currently empty) initialization argument holder brackets. Try with tris:

```
let chat_log_controller = ChatLogController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chat_log_controller)
present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: with i put in () i get the error Cannot call value of non-function type 'ChatLogController?'   - fix it delete ()

Comment: also its a storyboard going to a VC not using storyboard